# How to sort str in Python using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, sorting

```
a = np.array(10,2,3,1,20,30) #I got it from the Input.
b = np.sort(a)
```

it gives me a result `[1,10,2,20,3,30]` instead of `[1,2,3,10,20,30]`

Comment: If you got the array from `input`, you have to convert all of the arguments to `int` first.  (`input` always returns a `str`.)

Comment: ...in Python 3, that is, it always returns a string; presumably the OP is coming from an older version of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting input and adding it into an array the "numbers" will be `str` and not `ints`. You would need to first convert the input to take in `int` rather than `str`

#### Change input to be a `int`:

```py
user_in = int(input()) # ex: '4'
print(type(user_in)) # <class 'int'>
```

Notice how I am using the `int()` around the `input()` casting the users input from a `str` to an `int`.

Now the input could be added to an array and you will get the expected results due to the values being integers and not strings.

#### Modify the existing items in the list to be `int`:

Another approach is to change the array that contains the numbers as strings to `ints`. You could `map()` over all items in the array to change them to `int`.

```py
arr = list(map(int, arr))
```

This would go through your list and change every item to be of type `int`

Comment: This is correct, but I would also recommend initially storing the input as a string, and capturing the int cast from string in a `try: ... except: ...` block to ensure the program does not crash if the user inputs something that cannot be converted to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([10,2,3,1,20,30])
print(np.sort(arr))
```

This works fine. Firstly create a list before you try sorting it.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy when writing code, and your question counts.

Your sample array produces an error:

```
In [69]: a = np.array(10,2,3,1,20,30)                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-d65567166292> in <module>
----> 1 a = np.array(10,2,3,1,20,30)

TypeError: array() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

Changing that to be a list of integers:

```
In [70]: a = np.array([10,2,3,1,20,30])                                                              
In [71]: a                                                                                           
Out[71]: array([10,  2,  3,  1, 20, 30])
```

Sort does what you want:

```
In [72]: np.sort(a)                                                                                  
Out[72]: array([ 1,  2,  3, 10, 20, 30])
```

But if the input was a string or list of strings:

```
In [73]: a = np.array('10,2,3,1,20,30'.split(','))                                                   
In [74]: a                                                                                           
Out[74]: array(['10', '2', '3', '1', '20', '30'], dtype='<U2')
In [75]: np.sort(a)                                                                                  
Out[75]: array(['1', '10', '2', '20', '3', '30'], dtype='<U2')
```

The sort is string lexical. And the use of quotes to show strings is clear.